# inject local script in vue.js app to different components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I searched for an answer, but i cant found out an answer to my problem.

I'm working on a vue project, using vue-cli , and i need to inject different scripts to different pages (i use vue-router), more details incomming:

Here is what i have:

```
o public
|
|-index.html
|
|-js
| |-script_for_all_pages.js
| |-script_for_index1.js
| |-script_for_index2.js ...

o src (my vue project)
```

here is what i want:

1. i want to have a `<script src="js/script_for_all_pages.js"></script>` in the html of localhost/*
2. i want to have a `<script src="js/script_for_index1.js"></script>` in the html of localhost/index1
3. i want to have a `<script src="js/script_for_index2.js"></script>` in the html of localhost/index2

i did the first step by adding the `<script>` tag to the index.html in my public folder, but i cant figure out how to do the two last steps. thoses routes (localhost/indexx) are components, so i guess i should inject my script into the component `index1.vue`, but i have a bunch of errors when i try just importing it with `import "../js/index.js";`. And i cant figure out how to do it, whatever i try.

List of package that didnt work:

[vue-inject-js](https://github.com/rnkit/vue-inject-js)

[vue-plugin-load-script](https://github.com/tserkov/vue-plugin-load-script)

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it in Vue/React, just have this function in a helper and call it from any component on creation:

```
public injectScript(url, loadAsync=true): HTMLScriptElement {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = loadAsync;
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    return script;
}
```

Ignore the types if you are using JS. You can also use the returned script object to track events:

```
const script = injectScript("...");
script.onLoad = () => {/*do something*/}
```

Also, make sure to keep this limited to external widgets. **If this is your code, surely there's a better way**.

Comment: Gonne mark your answer as accepted, but i wont be able to try it, because I re-wrote all scripts in vue. Thanks anyway!